# Call a function from list and create data frame for all elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list, and my function

```
# Function to extract info for each address

def extract_restaurant_data(address):
 places_result = gmaps.places(address)
 place_id = places_result['results'][0]['place_id']


 try:
    user_ratings_total = place['result']['user_ratings_total']
    rating = place['result']['rating']

 except:
    print("No data")
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    ['user_ratings_total': user_ratings_total,
    'rating': rating}], columns=['user_ratings_total', 'rating'])

 return df1
```

This is the way that I am calling my function

```
result = [extract_restaurant_data(restaurant) for restaurant in myListAddresses]
```

I was expecting to have a data frame as output, with the length of my list myListAddresses. But my output is a list without format as this:

```
[                     user_ratings_total                      rating  \
 0  234  3.5  
 
                                              rating  \
 0  4.5] ...
```

I would like to know. How can I call my function extract_restaurant_data for each element in myListAddresses and get as result a data frame with all the information of each restaurant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do:

```
result = pd.concat([extract_restaurant_data(restaurant) for restaurant in myListAddresses])
```